# TYPO3 E-Mail Spam Protection

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-9.x

I’ve got a Problem with spam protection in TYPO3 v9.5 for a long time in my *own template extension* and *custom content elements*.

I would expect, that the E-Mail Links inserted via TypoLink in ckEditor would be transformed to name(at)domain.de in the frontend by using the following snippet in my Setup. But its simply is ignored:

`config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = 2
config.spamProtectEmailAddresses_atSubst = <span>(at)</span>`

I’ve set up a clean Installation with 9.5.15 and it just works. So I think it has something to do with my template-extension or my custom components with custom ckEditor config.

Can someone with a better understanding of TYPO3 please guide me to the right direction?

Here is my TCA for the Textfield:

```
    'bodytext' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'Kontaktdaten',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 40,
            'rows' => 3,
            'softref' => 'rtehtmlarea_images,typolink_tag,email[subst],url',
        ],
        'defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css]'
    ],
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1):

compare your TCA field configuration with the configuration of the field `tt_content.bodytext`

I guess you missed: `config.softref = typolink_tag,images,email[subst],url`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Bernd. I added my TCA code in the description above. I can´t see any error.